# React Native Navigation with custom transition and disabled lazy loading?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need tool for implementation navigation whith custom transition and disabled lazy loading for screens. For custom transition I have **createStackNavigator** *(but it does not have option lazy)*, for lazy I have **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** *(but it does not have options for custom transition).*

I try combine **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** and **createStackNavigator**, but this did not work.

Any ideas on how to impelemnt this thing.Thanks beforehands.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a custom navigator that is lazy and has custom transitions. Please read the guide starting at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigator-overview.html

Comment: Hi thnx, i read this docs, can you say what you mean or give an example, bacouse i note see solution in docs